# Accepted answer with OP saying it isn't helpful

Tags: discussion, questions

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35650705/1468942) there are several answers (most of them helpful I think) but nonetheless the OP keeps saying it doesn't work in comments.

There is a specific answer made by the OP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35651981/1468942) (on the same question) that explains none of the answers were valid for him and he found another way to solve it.

BUT; there is an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35651109/1468942) that it didn't help the OP as he himself says on the comments.

I don't know if I should flag it, inform the OP or actually do something at all.

Comment: Well, it's completely on behalf of the OP where they accept. May be they accepted one of the other answers arbitrary to earn 2 ptts rep. _"I don't know if I should flag it"_ No, I see no reason what you should flag there.

Comment: yeah, probably that, it just upset me a little it might no be the answer and in fact what the OP answered might be.

Comment: It looks to me like he managed to make it work, and accepted the answer without further comment.  I think I might have done that a couple of times myself.

Comment: Yep, I liken it to bounties I've placed on questions, when no one has given me an answer I will still award the bounty to the best answer as a way of appreciation for the effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't flag it; there's nothing the moderators can do about that. We can't make an OP change his or her choice of accepted answer, even if it makes no sense. And there's no indication of fraud here, like the OP and the author posting on each other's posts disproportionately.

You left a comment that makes sense. That's what I would have done. Hopefully, OP will explain. But probably, it's just what [Robert said in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317783/accepted-answer-with-op-saying-it-isnt-helpful#comment314182_317783):

> It looks to me like he managed to make it work, and accepted the answer without further comment. I think I might have done that a couple of times myself.

Answer (score -1):

Even if you flag it, noone except asker can unaccept the answer.

If you want, you can ask him to accept some other answer.

I think, in that situation he had to accept his own one. In fact for that moment it was the only one with solution - do modification in the other place and provide clear expression to the helper.